How can I make colored Wick contractions?
I was wondering if and how the simplewick package can be modified to accept a second optional input: color. I would like to make Wick contractions that are colored, i.e. I want the connecting lines to be colored.
MWE:
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{simplewick}

\begin{document}
$\bcontraction{}{A}{BCD}{E}\bcontraction[2ex]{A}{B}{C}{D}ABCDE$
\end{document}

This produces the following:


welcome! please post a minimal example which produces a regular black-and-white wick contraction. this should be complete i.e. we should be able to copy the code, paste it into a new file and compile it. if you've tried to add colour, please explain what you did and what happened, but just a non-coloured example is probably enough.

In best case, once you understood the packages code, you can use it AND redefine some commands via \renewcommand. Worst case, you need to change code on a copy.

The \acontraction and \bcontraction macros are rather short, they just choose the appropriate size based on \mathchoice and then call the internal macros \acontraction@ and \bcontraction@ respectively.
Therefore you can renew those commands to add the extra optional color argument.
With two optional arguments you always need to give the first if you want to give the second, but with a bit extra trouble you can allow for the first one to be empty, i.e., [], and assign the default value also in that case.
Examples of all variants (no optional arguments given, only the first given, both given, first empty and second given):
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{simplewick}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand{\acontraction}{ O{1ex} O{black} m m m m}{%
  \tl_if_empty:nTF{#1}{\def\wickoffset{1ex}}{\def\wickoffset{#1}}%
  {\color{#2}%
  \mathchoice
    {\acontraction@\displaystyle{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{\wickoffset}}%
    {\acontraction@\textstyle{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{\wickoffset}}%
    {\acontraction@\scriptstyle{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{\wickoffset}}%
    {\acontraction@\scriptscriptstyle{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{\wickoffset}}}}%
\RenewDocumentCommand{\bcontraction}{ O{1ex} O{black} m m m m}{%
  \tl_if_empty:nTF{#1}{\def\wickoffset{1ex}}{\def\wickoffset{#1}}%
  {\color{#2}%
  \mathchoice
    {\bcontraction@\displaystyle{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{\wickoffset}}%
    {\bcontraction@\textstyle{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{\wickoffset}}%
    {\bcontraction@\scriptstyle{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{\wickoffset}}%
    {\bcontraction@\scriptscriptstyle{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{\wickoffset}}}}%
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
$\acontraction{}{A}{BCD}{E}\acontraction[2ex]{A}{B}{C}{D}ABCDE$

$\acontraction[1ex][blue]{}{A}{BCD}{E}\acontraction[2ex][red]{A}{B}{C}{D}ABCDE$

$\bcontraction{}{A}{BCD}{E}\bcontraction[2ex][green]{A}{B}{C}{D}ABCDE$

$\bcontraction[][red]{}{A}{BCD}{E}\bcontraction[2ex]{A}{B}{C}{D}ABCDE$
\end{document}



As a quick hack, you could smuggle in some colour and then redefine the colour as needed:
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{simplewick}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{rulecolor}{.}
\AddToHook{cmd/bcontraction@@/before}{\color{rulecolor}}

\begin{document}
$
  {
    \colorlet{rulecolor}{red}
    \bcontraction{}{A}{BCD}{E}
  }
  \bcontraction[2ex]{A}{B}{C}{D}ABCDE
$
\end{document}


